# Energy-band diagrams of heterojunctions

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I'm studying heterojunctions and I'm struggling with drawing their energy-band diagrams. I've been looking for books or something to look up how the diagrams can turn out to be with different types of heterojunctions.

So far, I've been reading *Semiconductor physics and devices* by Neamen but he only talks about a certain type of heterojunctions, the *straddling* ones, and he doesn't analyze what happens with the *staggered* and *broken-gap*. Is there any resource where I could find these?